# level series in a highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm approaching for the first time with the highchart and i made a chart with a combination of two series in this way

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    title: {
        text: "Prova Combinato"
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'PRECIPITAZIONI (mm)'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Misure',
        color: '#4572A7',
        type: 'spline'
    }, {
        name: 'Temperature',
        color: '#89A54E',
        type: 'column'
    }]

}
```

then in two ajax calls i fill the data of the series in this way

options.series[0].data = series;
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

options.series[1].data = series2;
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

but in the layout, the "spline" serie is under the "column" serie. 
How can i do to put the "spline" over the "column". How can i set the levels of the series?

thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [index](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.index) parameter in series